# Работа с базой данных на node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, веб-программирование

Я пытаюсь сделать проверку наличия логина на базе mysql через node js. Примерно так:`

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();


var db = mysql.createConnection({
host: "localhost",
database: "localhost",
users: "root",
password: "..."});

db.connect();

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
var login = ....
let sql = "select logins from users";
db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
if(err) throw err;
console.log(result);
});
});
```

`

В переменной result всё есть, всё работает, но как достать её из функции db.query? Я так и не догадался. Помогите)))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0):

Вы столкнулись с явлением асинхронных вызовов с колбеками. Тут нужно смириться с тем, что асинхронность «заразна» — если вы уже стали использовать такие методы, всю дальнейшую логику придётся помещать внутрь колбеков. Вы не можете достать переменную из функции `db.query()`, вместо этого дальнейший код нужно помещать внутрь этой функции и использовать его в области видимости этой переменной.

Есть ещё один выход: объявить колбек в функции `app.post()` асинхронным и использовать внутри него API базы данных с промисами: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#using-promise-wrapper